# Understanding a range function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, range, key

So, I'm new to programming and I am having a bit of a trouble here. See, I wanted to write a small range function, like `range(a,b)` that would return an array with all numbers between a and b. So I googled and found this one:

```
const range = (min, max) => [...Array(max - min + 1).keys()].map(i => i + min);
```

This works perfectly fine, but I'm having a bit of trouble undertanding it, especially with the `.keys()` part. I thought `.keys()` was an Object function, that would return the key of a key/value pair of an object, but here it seems to me that it's been used in an Array.

What am I understanding wrong here?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: In JavaScrip an array is (also) an object whose keys are the array indexes. In fact `typeof [1, 2, 3]` will return `'object'`

Comment: @secan - While that's true, the `keys` method on an array is fundamentally different from the `Object.keys` method typically used with (non-array) objects. It *doesn't* return an array of the object's own properties, it returns an iterator for the valid indexes of the array (even if they're unpopulated, which the above relies on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays also have a [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) method and it's central to this `range` function working as it should.

Here's how that works:

1. It creates an empty ([sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)) array of the appropriate length (`Array(max - min + 1)`).
2. It gets an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) for the valid indexes of that array (`.keys()`). Valid indexes in an arrays are the numbers `0` through the length of the array minus one. (Technically, in specification terms, the indexes of arrays are string property names like `"0"`, `"1"`, etc., but the `keys` iterator returns numbers because we typically use numbers to index into arrays and that's the more useful value to provide.)
3. It [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the elements from that iterator out into an array (`[...]`).
4. It creates a new array by mapping each value in the array from #3, adding the `min` value to them (`.map(i => i + min)`).

Note that this creates multiple intermediate arrays and other objects. It's unlikely to matter, but it can be done much more efficiently. For instance, with `Array.from` as [shown by Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70348615/157247), or even just a simple loop:

```
const range = (min, max) => {
    const result = [];
    for (let n = min; n < max; ++n) {
        result.push(n); // Or: `result[result.length] = n;` if you want to
                        // avoid the function call
    }
    return result;
};
```

```js
const range = (min, max) => {
    const result = [];
    for (let n = min; n < max; ++n) {
        result.push(n);
    }
    return result;
};
console.log(range(5, 10));
```

That's not nearly as cool-looking, though. :-D

**But**, I probably wouldn't have `range` return an array at all unless I know for sure that's the end product I'm always going to need. Instead, I'd have it return an iterator:

```js
const range = function*(min, max) {
    for (let n = min; n < max; ++n) {
        yield n;
    }
};
        
for (const value of range(0, 10)) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

You can always spread it out into an array (or use it with `Array.from`) if you need an array.

Comment: This is marvelous, thanks so much! So, in a cheaty way, can I say that the keys in the array are the indexes?

Comment: @jampamatos - You're not even cheating, `keys` is defined as providing an iterator for the valid indexes of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) as well and returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) for returning keys. This requires a spreading into an array or use a function which takes [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) and returns an array.

For this purpose [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is made - and this has a mapping function as well.

Instead of builing more than one array, you could take `Array.from` directly with an object with a `length` property and a mapping function.

```js
const range = (min, max) => Array.from(
        { length:  max - min + 1 },
        (_, i) => i + min
    );

console.log(...range(7, 9));
```